# If statement , checking a string against another string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we put any OR  seperated conditions and checking a string against another string variable  in IF statement as i mentioned in below image , can some one please let me know the reason it is giving output as yes . As per my knowledge output should be no .

```
if 'ROHAN' or '------' in 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH':
    print("yes")
else:
    print('No')
```

Getting output as YES , I am not getting how ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
print("yes") if "ROHAN" in "FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH" or "------" in  "FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH" else print('No')
```

What you are doing is

```
if 'ROHAN' or '------' in 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH': print("yes") else: print('No')
```

What the system does is

```
'ROHAN' or '------' = 'Rohan'
```

Now Try this

```
if "Rohan":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

You will realise the true came from that

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Jackson is mostly correct, but it does not explain what is happening with the `in 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH'`. If you look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) you can see that the precedence of the `in` operator is higher than the `or` operator. Which means that your expression is evaluated as if there were brackets like this:

```
if 'ROHAN' or ('------' in 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH'):
```

The `'------' in 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH'` evaluates to False and, as @Jackson said, the `'ROHAN'` evaluates to True. The resulting `or` of the True and False is True and so you always get the 'Yes' printed out.

Fixing your code can be done by doing separte `in` statements for each, but that can get cumbersome fast if there are a few you want to test. You can do it with a for loop or more 'pythonic' using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
word_list = ['ROHAN', '------', 'JOBS']
match_string = 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH'
matches = [word for word in word_list if word in match_string ]
```

or if you just want to know there was a match you can use [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) on the list:

```
word_list = ['ROHAN', '------', 'JOBS']
match_string = 'FJSDVBKSUERKJOBSH'
was_a_match = any([word for word in word_list if word in match_string])
```